# Errors to use pipenv after updating python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, ubuntu-20.04, pipenv

recently I have updated my default python to be 3.10 but I realized that some parts of my OS started to broke;

I can use `python -m venv venv` and it works like a charm, but if I try to activate a pipenv shell I do receive some errors
It has started by raising errors in the `collections.MutableMapping` so I changed it to `collections.abc.MutableMapping`... But it doesn't stop raising errors and I can't remove the pipenv.

When I try to pipenv shell or even pipenv --rm I do receive the same message error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidHeader' from 'requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/exceptions.py)
```

[image]

As I can't find references on how to fix this, any help you can provide will be really appreciated guys.

Regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

Running with a new Ubuntu 22.04 system, I faced the same urllib3 `collections` issue you report as your initial problem:

```
$ pipenv install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <snip>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

I found a discussion of this in the pipenv github's issue page here:
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5088

Apparently there is a problem with Python 3.10 with the apt-installed version of pipenv. I suppose the apt repositories should obtain an updated pipenv? In any case, taking the input from [amod-amatya](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5088#issuecomment-1113956382), I installed pipenv via `pip` (on my system, my packages are installed via `sudo`, but running as a non-sudo user should work as well):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pipenv
```

FWIW, I didn't uninstall the apt version of pipenv. With that pip-installed pipenv version, pipenv now works for me:

```
$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2022.5.2

$ pipenv install 
<snip>
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
_ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (1d3b5e)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (1d3b5e)...
  __   ________________________________ 3/3 _ 00:00:01
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```